# corona function to show ad when loaded does not work

Tags: lua, load, admob, coronasdk

I am trying to load an interstitial ad before actually showing it so that I can avoid lag. However everything I have tried has failed. With this code no ad ever appears:

```
local ads = require( "ads" )


ads.init( "admob", "ca-app-pub-2823622942892345/4361536298", adListener )
ads.load( "interstitial", { appId="ca-app-pub-2823622942892345/4361536298",
                            testMode=false } )

local function adListener( event )
  if ( event.isError ) then
    --Failed to receive an ad
  else
    ads.show( "interstitial", { x=0, y=0, appId="ca-app-pub-2823622942892345/4361536298" } )
  end
end
```

With this code the ad loads but with lag...

```
local ads = require( "ads" )


ads.init( "admob", "ca-app-pub-2823622942892345/4361536298", adListener )
ads.load( "interstitial", { appId="ca-app-pub-2823622942892345/4361536298", testMode=false } )

ads.show( "interstitial", { x=0, y=0, appId="ca-app-pub-2823622942892345/4361536298" } )
```

Does anyone now why it does not work? If so how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, your adListener function won't work.  Since it's a local function and declared after you use it the first time, it will be nil on that first use. That function needs to be higher up in your code before it's used the first time.

In your second example, the ads.load() is an asynchronous call, that means we know it can take a while to work, so control returns to your app immediately and then you call ads.show() before the as has loaded and therefore nothing shows.

There is a tutorial that may help you with this:

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/07/15/tutorial-implementing-admob-v2/